# how to open foursquare iOS application from other app, with search pre populated

Tags: iphone, ios, foursquare

I need to open foursquare app with pre-populated search from my app. how can this be done??

fsq gives following options to link specific views.

`Show a venue   foursquare://venues/VENUE_ID`

`Show a check-in    foursquare://checkins/CHECKIN_ID`

`Show a tip foursquare://tips/TIP_ID`

`Show a user    foursquare://users/USER_ID`

if I want to search new york

is there something like `foursquare://explore/new+york`

Comment: well I already read that, no help

Comment: Then how about, it not possible since there is not API for it.

Comment: Do you want to work with explore api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no registered foursquare deeplink to open up explore, but that's a great suggestion and we'll probably add one (it would likely be foursquare://venues/explore though)